# What data structure to use?

Tags: java, data-structures

I want to store information using data structure.

For example, I have a data similar to:

```
Code    Applicable values
001     A,B,C,D
004     C,D
005     P,Q,R,S
007     S,C
..
..
..
1000 (Code, Applicable values pair)
```

Straightforward solution I can think of is having `HashMap` with key type `String` and value type `HashSet`.

I was informed before by architect that having `Set` in `Map` is not a good idea.

Any suggestion on how to go about implementing this?

Comment: Did architect say why he doesn't like `HashMap<String, HashSet>`? What did he recommend to you instead?

Comment: Definitely looks like a perfect case for map<int, set> or map<int, vector> or so on.  (Or hash_map depending on your specific requirements.)

Comment: @stakx The reason he gave was 'more complexity' and he did not recommend anything.

Comment: Discarding perfect valid solutions IS more complexity :) Maybe the architect is confused with data structures. If you have good semantic methods that give meaningful value while masking data structure handling, you don't have to worry. `Map<Integer, Set>` (or `Map<String, Set>`) seems PERFECT for me.

Answer (score 1):

A `HashMap<String, HashSet<String>>` looks  just fine to me for holding the type of data you've shown.

That "architect" of yours might be right about too much complexity when we're talking about how that data structure is exposed to the rest of your program. For example:

- That type signature above does not make any statement about what kind of strings are used as keys, and what kind of values are in the value sets. Do they represent names? Or ISBN numbers? Or any text, or only particular enumeration values? etc.
- If you use such a `HashMap` everywhere in your code, when adding values into the sets you will have to remember everywhere to do two steps: (1) creating an empty set only if no value is in the dictionary for some given key, and (2) adding the new value to the set of a given key. Having to think about routine stuff like that opens up the door for bugs.

Perhaps it would be better to hide your actual data structure behind a nice, simple and easy-to-use "collection" interface, perhaps similar to the following:

```java
interface ApplicableValuesCollection
{
    void Add(int code, String value);
    void Remove(int code, String value);
    bool Contains(int code, String value);
    Iterable<String> GetValuesOfCode(int code);
    …
}
```

Comment: +1. I only should add a recommendation: declarations as interfaces and implementations as classes. Declaration `Map<String, Set<String>>` and implementation: `new HashMap...` and `new HashSet...`.

Comment: Also if the "architect" is complaining about the complexity because of the access to the structures... then he/she forgot encapsulation!!! (as @stakx recommends with the code sample)

Comment: @helios, I agree with _"declarations as interfaces and implementations as classes"_. Take note however that my main suggestion here is to not expose any dictionary *at all* (not even as an interface), but something higher-level instead.